# How long does it take Bruce Wayne to get into his Bat Suit?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy

First time posting a question, so I apologise for errors in advance!

I recently watched the The Dark Knight, and during the party scene Bruce heads into his panic-room and appears approx 3 mins later as a fully-dressed Batman.

So:

- Is there any canon references to how long it takes for Bruce to get ready?
- Does he have a quick-release system for turning back from Batman to Bruce, and if so does he carry stuff like deodorant/grooming products to ensure that he looks/smells like a billionaire?

Comment: Not too mention how fast he has to put on all that black eyeshadow, and how long it would take to clean off completely...

Comment: Only as long as it takes to slide down the Bat Pole.

Comment: I don't know if you're going to find anything canon from the Nolanverse Batman, but I'd imagine there's been a few references from the DC comics version, and maybe from one of the animated series.

Comment: The definitive answer is here; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXFsh-rDAP4

Comment: @Richard: Impressive for a fan-made suit-up scene, but no Hollywood director would allow nipples on the Batsuit...not to mention the gratuitous butt-shot.

Comment: @Jeff - You didn't mention the bat-crotch...

Comment: @Richard: My brain bleach is surprisingly effective.  I know not of what you speak.

Comment: @Jeff - http://cdn3.whatculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Batman-Leather-Thong.jpg

Comment: Do you know how billionaires smell?
Any way they damn well like.

Comment: Something that needs to be considered, that was approximately 3 minutes to the viewer, it could have been longer in terms of the Nolan-verse. Three minutes to us could have been 10 to them, if that universe was real. Basically time is relative to the scope of the scene.

Comment: Some indirect evidence that it could take a while: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5ezsReZcxU

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For a comparable real-world example, it takes less than 1 m 30 s to put on full firefighter gear. Video:

Eye makeup is available in spray cans, so this could be very quick. Just close your eyes and move the spray nozzle across your face a few times.

Allowing a few seconds for Bruce to strip down before putting on the Batsuit, it seems quite feasible for him to get ready in 3 minutes.

On the principle that taking gear off is quicker than putting it on correctly, he should be able to change back in a similar length of time. How he removes the makeup and manages to smell nice I'm not sure. It may be a job for the amazing chemistry skills of Lucius Fox.

Comment: They make make-up removal products that come in a wet-wipe form small enough to be carried in a pocket.  In the comics Alfred Pennyworth is a classically trained actor who would have experience in stage make-up (both application and removal) stage actor are known for their ability to change both costume and make-up faster than the scenery can change so I would imagine he's imparted some of the knowledge to Bruce as well.

Comment: @Monty129: Good point. As for general sweatiness from fighting bad guys while wearing full body armour, Bruce *is* known to be an eccentric billionaire. It may be that he just walks around being rather smelly after a quick change from Batman. People would assume he had not bothered to shower after his latest polo match, sexual activity, or whatever.

Comment: Wow - good answer, video & all. Also, in most continuities Bruce wears the basic Batsuit under his clothes (sans cowl, gloves, boots, & belt). That eliminates at least 50% of the time involved, probably more.

Comment: @Omegacron: Thanks! Although this question specifically mentioned the Christopher Nolan films, where Bruce pretty clearly doesn't wear the Batsuit under normal clothing.

Comment: I think if he did, all those ceramic plates would make him look...lumpy.  Not ideal to maintaining his playboy image.

Comment: Some great responses here - The video, and particularly the comments from @Monty129/@Royal Canadian Bandit, regarding Alfred's acting experience/Bruce's eccentricity.

As I'm assuming it's never been directly address in the comics/other media, I will consider it answered.

Comment: One thing needs to be considered here: unlike the firemen, superheroes for some reason like to put their suits on display dummies, making the job of a quick change decidedly harder.

Answer (score -1):

From the classic batman series in the sixties it takes about 5 seconds

Comment: Is this just a guess or do you have any evidence such as a video clip?

Comment: Watch any episode of adam wests batman

Comment: If memory serves, they usually jump on the batpoles, then the batswirly thing swirls, then they arrive in the batcave *an indeterminate time* later. Which means your answer is basically useless.

Comment: @Valorum - In one episode, they are shown to *automatically change into their costumes as they slide down the poles*. It takes considerably less than five seconds. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eO9LHPqScoY - at about 1:15.

Comment: @johnsensebe - Now *that* would make a good answer.

Comment: @Valorum - There's another episode where they have to use the Bat-poles without changing, and you can see there is a switch that turns off the automatic change. That would be even better, but I don't remember the name of that episode.